# About Database Synchronization

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I am Developing a Windows application using C# in .NET., It work properly.,
But the customer wants the output in Website also., How can it possible.?
Web Server and Locally Using Same Database.,I want to synchronize two database are same in every 15 second interval or updating data time?
Please give me a solution for this problem..

Comment: you can use web service or look into wcf, and if its only output then it seems easy.

Comment: if `Web Server` & `Windows app` use same database, why do you need to sync them?

Comment: You can just write jsonrpc service in your solution to gather info from db through its methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is a big topic and a non-trivial problem that you should do a lot of research into before deciding on a solution.  I've written some thoughts below, but these are by no means an exhaustive list of possible approaches or things that you should be wary of.

The first decision is whether the website and the app should use the same copy of the database, or whether you should have two separate copies of the database and keep them in sync using replication.

Replication is a big topic in itself as you need to think about how your resolve conflicts in data changes between the two copies of the database (e.g. if the same record gets changed on both databases).

You say in your question that the website will have "output", if that means that the website is only showing read-only data (i.e. no editing of the data on the website) then replication will be simpler as you only need to copy data to the website's copy of the database.

Another solution is for the web and desktop apps to share one copy of the database.  The questions then are where to host that database and how to access it.  At the moment you are probably using a database connection in your desktop app to access the database.  The least-coding solution to make the data available on the web would then be to host your website on the customer's network so that both the desktop app and website have access to the database.  However, that means your client is now hosting a website on their network, which has all sorts of potential issues (e.g. security, traffic volumes, uptime, etc.)

You could write a REST web-service (e.g. an ASP.NET WebAPI) to make the data available to the website from the customer's network, but again that would require you host a website (well, web service) from the customer's network.

An alternative approach is to place the database in the cloud and let the website and desktop app access it from there.  That removes the need to host a website on the customer network.  However, you will probably find that your desktop app will now be slower than you'd like because it is designed on the expectation of the data being nearby and fast to access.  If you've written the desktop app with an asynchronous data access structure that will be less of an issue, but if not you will probably find the desktop app slows down.

However, if the data in the database is at all sensitive you may find your customer is unhappy with that data being in the cloud.  If that's the case then you need to be wary of that with the replication solution too - you should ensure you are only replicating the data needed for the website to the website's copy of the database.

Yet another solution is to make the locally hosted database available to the remotely hosted website via TCP (SQL Server can do that), but again there are security issues to consider and again you need to think about whether you customer's network and internet connections are reliable and resilient enough to provide the data for a website in real-time.

To get to the right solution you need to consider (amongst other things) whether data will be edited on both the website and the app, either now or in the future and also to think about the likely number of users of the website now and in the future.  This is a discussion you'll need to include the customer in too.

Comment: Great points, all of them, and thank you for the effort. However that makes this question so bad: it's what we call "too broad". There are way too many possible solutions, each of which warrants an own answer going in detail and providing links to other resources, hell, for each of your paragraphs you can buy multiple books on the subject. In fact, for each of the subjects there exist questions. OP must show their research and their reasoning (i.e. respond to the comments posted to the question) before this question is even remotely answerable.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree, I was really just trying to demonstrate that their's a huge amount to consider and give the OP some things to research.